# How to resolve the Migration Errors?

Tags: mysql, django

I have two models ie; Model1 and Model2. One field in Model2 acted as a foreign key of Model1. Here Primary Key of Model1 is 'id'. But now i modified the primary key field, removed id and added field called **demo_num** as primary key.Now my models looke like

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  dem_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
   dem_fk = models.Foreignkey('Model1')
```

but when i am doing migrate it is showing error like,

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1829, "Cannot drop column 'id': needed in a foreign key constraint of table Model2)

How to solve this problem?

**Note**:
    Without deleting migrations file I want to do it

Comment: you need to clean your `Model2` or create data migration, any way you have to be ensure: that no other solution then to change the 'PK` field

Answer (score 0):

first create new primary key `dem_num` without deleting `id` in Model1

```
class Model1(models.Model):
   dem_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Then link this field as a foreign key to Model2

```
class Model2(models.Model):
   dem_fk = models.Foreignkey('Model1', to_field='dem_num')
```